# Email address deleted from profile keeps reappearing

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-copying

I have Stack Overflow, Meta and Super User accounts. I have been trying to remove my email from my profile. So I delete the email and then choose:

> "Save and copy profile to all Stack Exchange Accounts"

A couple of days later, somehow the email addres is again showing in my profile. If an admin is seeing this, I'm asking to remove my email from your system before you fix the bug.

Comment: Noone can see that information except for yourself and moderators. Is there a particular reason why you are removing your email?

Comment: Yes for privacy purposes. I think I have the right to do so.

Comment: You need to relax. I was just wandering if you knew that it did not show to everyone because some people have missed that in the past.

Comment: @SNash you can choose to believe what you want because nothing that is said will change your mind, but I haven't actually voted yet because I don't know if this is a legit bug or not (specifically, if the field is optional or not).  Because if it is actually "optional", then you should be able to remove it.

Comment: Also, from what I can see in your account profile and history as a moderator, this is [tag:status-norepro]. I won't go into detail without your consent.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If you edit out your email then the hint in the box itself says its optional

Comment: @RichardTingle Do you think it could possible be getting set back because of his gravatar then? Because the hint also notes that it is used for that purpose.

Comment: @JoshMein I was wondering the same.  What happens if you don't provide a profile picture or an email address, do you still get an automatically generated gravatar?

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just tested that and you go back to a automatically generated gravatar.

Comment: What *kind* of email did you get when you weren't expecting it

Comment: Just wondering, did you make any other changes other than email? Were they retained or did they rollback as well?

Comment: @AnnaLear Can you provide a more detail answer?

Comment: Could this be related to it being a "cookie" account prior to adding the email address? I don't recall if those were given a profile page or not - but it could fit the chain of events: used a cookie account, added email creating a regular account, no path back once an email is entered?

Comment: @JoshMein I don't have one. All I got right now is "huh, that's weird. we shouldn't be restoring the emails as far as I know." Assuming this can be verified and reproduced, this is a valid bug report.

Comment: @S Nash Based on the linked duplicate by Bart, this issue was reported earlier this year, but it was marked as status-by-design. If you would like to make this a feature request for this to be changed please update your question to indicate this.

Comment: Ironically, by posting here and asking for your email removed due to 'privacy'.. inevitably the only accounts that can look at your email are then moderators and you just requested them to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked through your profile and its history, and I don't see what you describe happening. My understanding of your issue is this:

1. At some point you edited in your email address into your profile.
2. At some other point, you edited it back out.
3. It always reappears a 'couple days' later, without you having done anything to cause that to happen.

I won't go into detail without your consent, but I don't see that pattern in your profile and history.

Comment: Ok I will close of this question. You can name it bug or feature, but current behavior is **BAD**

Comment: This can happen if OP uses SE's Open ID, which is email based. Even if you remove the email from your profile, that field is populated the next time you login with SE's Open ID. I'm not sure if it happens for Gmail/Yahoo as well, but my guess is that it doesn't.