# Prevent Automatic Updates of Profile from Google / Yahoo Logins

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, login, privacy

Every time I login using my Yahoo account, my profile is automatically updated to include my email ID and Real Name from my Yahoo Account. I find this disconcerting and irritating, as I do not wish to <strike>share any data through my profile with the public</strike> include this data in my profile, if I don't have to.

Yes, I know that every time I login through Yahoo, I get a warning that my name and email will be shared with SE. However, I don't expect SE to automatically add this to my profile when I keep deleting it.

Is there an option to turn this off somewhere? Or do I need to migrate my account?

<strike>If not, **Feature Request**: SE shouldn't play with its users profile and add / delete / update data, especially without warning the user.</strike>

---

**Added**: My point is that I do not want any data added to the profile unless I have personally included it. Apart from the fact that the name associated with my Yahoo account is not my real name, it is irritating that I have to keep checking my profile to see if SE has "meddled" with it in nay way!

---

The issue here is of privacy. <strike>Sure, the current policy is that you may not display this data publicly now. But what if you pull a Google and decide that you will?</strike>

---

**Clarification on the 'Privacy' aspect**:

Yes, I know the terms I agreed to, and I am fine with it. But all of you seem to be in a hurry with the "duplicate question" and the down-votes, without actually trying to understand the issues:

1. The data associated with my Yahoo account automatically being added to the profile.
2. The ambiguity of data collection and handling, that creates false expectation of privacy, by the SE user interface for profile editing.

Details - As stated earlier, my Yahoo account doesn't have my real name. So adding this in the profile automatically, even if it is for SE reference only, doesn't make sense. If you need to "prevent abuse" or for other legal use, isn't it better to just log the Yahoo / Google account data separately rather than adding it to the profile **where the user can remove it**??

Which brings me to the second point - a **false expectation of privacy** is created here by allowing users to delete the name and email ID, if you are automatically going to add it every time!

(Example - Google / Yahoo / Microsoft (GYM) enhanced their profiling ability by simply removing the "sign-out / logout" link and moving it to a drop-down menu. This confused users so much that they simply closed the browsers without logging out which enabled GYM to profile them more effectively!)

**Stop thinking of this only from a technical perspective** of open ID's or oAuth's.

**The point here is not that the data is being collected** by SE. If SE requires a user's name and email ID, sure, I will give it to you. The thing is that the SE UI is being ambiguous on communicating this to the user. **It appears disingenuous if you allow a user to delete info, and then keep adding it automatically without informing the user.** Why allow a user to delete the info - in effect indirectly conveying to him / her that the data isn't necessary / required - if you want it in the first place? 
Perhaps my **feature request** should be stated as -

1. Maintain a distinction between 'account information' and 'user profile' to remove any ambiguity or confusion on the personal data collected and its use.
2. SE may edit a "user account" information (and intimate the user of the changes), but shouldn't edit a users "profile".

Comment: Only you (and moderators) can see this information.

Comment: Only moderators can see your real name and email in your profile.

Comment: That doesn't matter - I do not want it in my profile at all in the first place. Why am I forced to delete it manually everytime?

Comment: You are not 'forced' to do anything. You expressly *agreed* to it all at multiple points along the way. If you don't want it in your profile, delete it. But, you already know that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email address deleted from profile keeps reappearing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197991/email-address-deleted-from-profile-keeps-reappearing/197998#197998)

Comment: *"But what if you pull a Google and decide that you will?"* ... that would be in violation of the TOS you agreed to.

Comment: @Bart: To come back to main issue - why have this ambiguity in the first place? Just don't add the data automatically without informing the user! And if you want the data, have a necessary REQUIRED field.

Comment: Meh, given that you've agreed to it, and the information is useful, perhaps that field should not be editable by you in the first place.

Comment: You do realize that since you have authorized SE with your OpenID Connect, they can easily fetch the email without your knowledge anyway. If you're so concerned about your email, use a different OpenID.

Comment: @Manishearth & Stijn: You didn't even read my question did you? I have clearly stated in my question that I am AWARE that the data (my name and email ID) is being shared with SE.

Comment: @Sam No, I'm saying that removing the email address doesn't mean that they lose access to it. The have your OpenID, _they can fetch the email address without you logging in whenever they want_. Not that they do that, but still. In your post you've only mentioned that you authorize SE to have your email when you login.

Comment: Also, from your 2nd proposal, note that the email on the profile is only visible to you and moderators. I don't see what difference it makes if the email is stored in "user account information" (which would probably be mod-visible) or on the profile, visible to only a select few. It seems like a change of nothing more than terminology.

Comment: You may be interested in [this feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97964/make-clear-which-profile-data-is-visible-to-whom)

Comment: @Manishearth: Please read my clarifications in the question. This is about the ambiguity of data collection. Being technically inclined we understand how our data can be collected. But someone who visits a non-technical forum of SE will think that when he / she deletes his email ID from his / her profile, he / she is NOT sharing this info with SE.

Comment: @Manishearth: Please read my updated question again.

Comment: After all your revisions, it seems to be a perfect dupe of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169353/cannot-remove-email-from-my-profile-page). It wasn't in the past, but now that it's clear that it's not about a privacy violation, it's the same thing.  Bounty the other post with your concerns, or comment on Kevin's answer.

Comment: @Kevin: How can the moderators see my real name if I delete it. If I can delete it, why do you keep adding it? If it is for the TOS, then why can I delete it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/656/discussion-between-sam-and-manishearth)

Answer (score 2):

The only people who can see that information are moderators, stack exchange employees, and yourself. You agreed to this in the terms and conditions (and the privacy policy) when you signed up for an account. In addition, an OpenID is meant to be something that is tied to your identity.

As for what moderators see, when we visit your profile, we see this (not your profile; someone else's):

[image]

We only see this information when we require it (such as preventing abuse/spam)

See also:

- https://stackexchange.com/legal
- https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy
- https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement

Comment: Then why can I delete it in the first place?

Comment: @Sam Say... to update it?

Comment: And good point to Hiroto here about the fact that you agree to how this all works when you sign up, and *also* when you connect your login to your account... and *also* when you log in each time. Does *no one* read those agreements? (rhetorical question, of course)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: The claim being made here is that it is a REQUIRED field! If it is a required field, then the a user shouldn't be able to delete it in the first place right?! Do you understand my confusion now? You are telling me it is ok to delete the info, but then you keep adding it yourself!!

Comment: @Sam you can edit it. Editing something to be empty isn't deleting it; it's editing it to be empty~ (The same way `"" !== null`). Also, every time you log in you agree to populate that field with up-to-date information.

Comment: @AndrewBarber I think only the IT Security guys, lawyers, moderators and employees read those agreements (but no data, of course)

Comment: @Hiroto: Let's not play with words here. If a field needs to be editable, and is also required, you tell the user that a null edit is unacceptable.

Comment: @Sam If *that's* really what you are objecting to here, I don't think this at all counts as a privacy issue, as your question states.

Comment: @Sam read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169353/cannot-remove-email-from-my-profile-page already, it's explained rather clearly there.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: I'll update the question.